How to avoid a space being added for a newline after an include
Our docs are written in Asciidoc and published with Antora.
I am using an include for some repeated snippets (e.g. contact us). Per asciidoc rules, each include has to be on its own line. However, a newline forces a space, which is fine if I need one for the text that follows. But if it's just a full-stop/period that follows, this looks odd as it has a space before it like this . instead of what I want like this.:

This is my current asciidoc (which uses two different partials):
include::partial$contact-support.adoc[]
if you would like to request a feature or get support. You can also join the 
include::partial$decodable-slack.adoc[]
.


I can't include the full-stop in the partial as it doesn't always get used at the end of the sentence.
I could create separate partials for in/end of sentence but it's a bit clumsy
I could also rewrite the sentence to put the partial at the end of it. Again, clumsy.

Any suggestions on how to do this in asciidoc? thanks!

Instead of include, define the boilerplate itself as a macro and put a macro reference in your text. The HTML of the macro definition can go into a passthru so that it is passed along to Asciidoctor's HTML renderer.
Example:
:boilerplate: pass:[<i>stuff goes here</i>]

Time for some {boilerplate}.

Result:


The reason you get the extra space is because the include::[] macro behaves as a block element, not an inline element, and block elements always have newlines. The newline is whitespace before the period.
@matt's suggestion to use an attribute is the right one. You must use the pass:[] macro if the attribute value has AsciiDoc markup, and you need to enable the appropriate substitutions.
For example:
:insertme: pass:q[this is _special_ content]


FYI: You should look at "{insertme}" for details.

Be careful about using HTML markup in passthrough blocks. That works great if your output format is HTML, but does not work in PDF or DocBook.
